# Using property of parent class gives "unknown property" error in php (yii2)

Tags: php, inheritance, gridview, properties, yii2

I'm using yii2 and the `yii2-grid` gridview extension of Kartik. I get the exception `Setting unknown property: kartik\grid\GridView::autoIdPrefix` at the initialization of the `GridView::widget`. However the inheritance of `kartik\grid\GridView` is `yii\grid\GridView » yii\widgets\BaseListView » yii\base\Widget » yii\base\Component » yii\base\Object` and `yii\base\Widget` has the public parameter `autoIdPrefix`.

I'am using the following initialization:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'autoIdPrefix' => 'igl_' . $model->id,
    'showHeader' => false,
    'columns' => [
        [ 'attribute' => 'language' ],
        [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'value' => 'name',
            'editableOptions' => [
                'formOptions' => [
                    'action' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/ingredient-group-lang'])
                ]
            ]

        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property $autoIdPrefix is a static property of the widget class, and so is not inherited by child classes. If you need to change the id of the widget I suggest setting it directly, so

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'id' => 'igl_' . $model->id,
'showHeader' => false,
'columns' => [
    [ 'attribute' => 'language' ],
    [
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute' => 'name',
        'value' => 'name',
        'editableOptions' => [
            'formOptions' => [
                'action' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/ingredient-group-lang'])
            ]
        ]

    ],
],
```

]); ?>